# Why is this generic type not erasing to specified class

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following Java code:

```
public class Program {
    static class Value {
        public String getString() {
            return "value";
        }
    }

    static class BetterValue extends Value {
        public String getBetterString() {
            return "better_value";
        }
    }

    static class Container<V extends Value> {
        public final V value;

        // EDIT #2: to mitigate the NPE:
        public Container(V value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    static class BetterContainter<V extends BetterValue> extends Container<V> {
        // EDIT #2: to mitigate the NPE:
        public BetterContainter(V value) {
            super(value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // EDIT #2: to mitigate the NPE:
        Container container = new Container(new Value());
        System.out.println(container.value.getString());

        // EDIT #2: to mitigate the NPE:
        BetterContainter betterContainer = new BetterContainter(new BetterValue());
        System.out.println(betterContainer.value.getBetterString());
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get:

```
Error:(28, 49) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getBetterString()
  location: variable value of type V
```

Shouldn't the field 'value' in BetterContainer erase to BetterValue? Why does it erase to Value for Container then?

EDIT: To mitigate the "don't use raw types" arguments and bring the question closer to what I'm acctually dealing with, suppose adding this code:

```
static class Consumer<C extends Container> {
  protected final C container;

  public Consumer(C container) {
    this.container = container;
  }

  public void consume() {
    System.out.println(container.getValue().getValue());
  }
}

static class BetterConsumer<C extends BetterContainer> extends Consumer<C> {

  public BetterConsumer(C container) {
    super(container);
  }

  @Override
  public void consume() {
    System.out.println(container.getValue().getBetterValue());
  }
}
```

How would I solve being able to do

`System.out.println(container.getValue().getBetterValue());`

without casting?

Comment: What do you mean by 'default'? There is no such thing in Java Generics. Do you mean 'erase'? And if so, why shouldn't it erase to `Value`?

Comment: Raw types strike again. They are confusing as all hell and there is no reason to use them in new code. Just remember to *always* provide type parameters when the type requires them.

Comment: @user207421, yes I mean erase. And I don't mind it defaulting to Value, I mind it not defaulting to BetterValue for BetterContainer.

Comment: I edited my original question because I oversimplified it and to a point where your potential solutions cannot actually be implemented. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: If you mean 'erase' why are you continuing to say 'default'? Don't misuse standard terminology. And if you don't mind it 'defaulting' to one type how can you possibly object to it not 'defaulting' to another type? You aren't making sense.

Comment: @user207421, you are correct, I edited it out.

Comment: But not from your title. And you haven't answered my second question.

Comment: @user207421, I didn't realize you can edit the title after posting. To answer your second question, I don't mind it erasing to Value in the case of Consumer, I mind it not erasing to BetterValue in the case of BetterConsumer.

Comment: So, again, what rational basis do you have for your expectation?

Comment: I have a train of reasoning (that is obviously faulty): The Container is a generic class that has a field of type V that must extend the Value class. The BetterContainer is a generic class that extends the Container class and further restricts its 'value' field type to extend BetterValue. So when I ask a BetterContainer instance for 'value', I would think that it should extend BetterValue.

Comment: @user207421 Or apparently, isn't faulty and I just omitted a wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Slaw's answer explains the why: when using raw types the V field in the Container class will be erased to Value, even if it is accessed from BetterContainer.

To fix the issue with the your consumer example, you need to add a type variable (the ? wildcard in this case) to the consumer classes:

```
static class Consumer<C extends Container<?>> {
    protected final C container;

    public Consumer(C container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void consume() {
        System.out.println(container.value.getString());
    }
}

static class BetterConsumer<C extends BetterContainer<?>> extends Consumer<C> {

    public BetterConsumer(C container) {
        super(container);
    }

    @Override
    public void consume() {
        System.out.println(container.value.getBetterString());
    }
}
```

While not necessary in your example, you could also use a bound type variable:

```
static class Consumer<T extends Value, C extends Container<T>> {
```

Comment: Yes, this solves it. The weird thing is, I use JDeveloper 11.1.1.4.0, and it shows no errors without the wildcards until compile time. I suppose that's the whole reason I posted this question, because I wasn't getting what was happening. The wildcards help with the compilation. I guess it's just one of many JDeveloper's bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```java
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BetterContainer container = ...;
    BetterValue value = container.getValue(); // compilation error
  }

  interface Value {}

  interface BetterValue extends Value {}

  interface Container<V extends Value> {
    V getValue();
  }

  interface BetterContainer<V extends BetterValue> extends Container<V> {}
}
```

This will give the following compilation error:

```
...\Main.java:7: error: incompatible types: Value cannot be converted to BetterValue
    BetterValue value = container.getValue();
                                          ^
```

Because, due to the use of raw types, the return type of `getValue()` has been erased to `Value`. This is despite the fact we have an instance of `BetterContainer` because the `getValue()` method is declared in `Container` and not `BetterContainer`. If you want the return type to be erased to `BetterValue` then you need to override the method:

```java
interface BetterContainer<V extends BetterValue> extends Container<V> {
  @Override V getValue();
}
```

Comment: So I should add an additional `V value` field in BetterContainer to hide the field from Container?

Comment: You _could_, but I doubt that would be practical. In any case, [waxwing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60928604/6395627) appears to have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a raw `BetterContainter` type.

Change it to:

```
BetterContainter<BetterValue> betterContainer = new BetterContainter<>();
```

Comment: I know I'm using a raw type, but the BetterContainer specifies the Value type should extends BetterValue, so even the raw type should default to this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited my question so it matches my true problem more precisely. I feel by oversimplifying I misguided you it to offer solutions I'm not sure I can sue.